# Proper laptop temperature for warmer enviroment

Tags: temperature

This is my laptop on idle mode with only Firefox running. Environment temperature is up to 15-20 C. It's an HP ProBook with Ati HD 4330. When I am writing codes for android with Eclipse core temperatures go up to 45-50 C. My issue is that when environment temperature elevates at 30-35 C my laptop is burning. CPU and GPU go up to 60-70 C and 70-80 C. With Win7 CPU and GPU are 10-15 C lower. Will ubuntu 12.04 breakdown my hardware due to high temperatures?

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp2:        +44.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp3:        +41.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp4:        +44.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp5:        +20.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp6:        +35.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +38.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +37.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeadetly high temperatures are never really healthy for the machine. In the long run this can lead for instance to cracked solderjoints on the processor/GPU because of the difference in thermal expansion of board and chip, but it can take a few years before you get into trouble with that.

Yes, your chips are okay with high temperature...your mainboard, however, is not really happy with it.

Normally, the main reason that the laptop runs 15  degrees hotter on ubuntu than on windows is the open source radeon videodriver.

When you install the (proprietary) fglrx driver from the ubuntu repository you will see a drop of 10 to 20 degrees in temperature on your laptop.

If you are already on fglrx, and the temperatures are still above what you desire:

1. avoid unneeded 3D eyecandy.
2. Install ***powertop*** to tweak your hardware for low energy consumption and to reveal the biggest CPU resource-hogs on your system.
3. You might prefer a lightweight desktopmanager like LXDE, that will free up to (or over) 50% of your system resources

When I'm running HD video on my netbook with GPU acceleration I have a CPU load of 90% to 100% on Ubuntu but a load of 20%-25% on Lubuntu (same netbook, same kernel, same drivers, same movie).

Comment: I have already installed Ati driver. My issue is at summer where i should be coding and watching Youtube tutorials.

Comment: I updated my answer with some extra tips

Answer (score 0):

Your system support up to 100°C!!! Unless you put your laptop on your legs or something flammable I don't see any problem, technically speaking.

Comment: So i can rely on these critical value from lm-sensors?

Comment: Yes. Linux sometimes has a little more temperature than Windows (since Windows has more contact with the makers) and is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0):

No. Although high temps are seen, the silicon is designed for it.

Although you have not provided the CPU type, I went looking for the hottest CPU packaged with the ATI HD 4330 in HP Probooks, and found that was the T9600. Its max operating temperature is 105 degrees Centigrade.  My six year old Lenovos run up to 80 degrees Centigrade with no problems.

However, you're free to contact HP with the model number of your lappie and find their maximum internal temp specification.

Comment: Thanks for your time. As i previously said watching youtube and coding at summer, it will be nightmare for my laptop.